# F-string not formatting floats into an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, f-string

Usually, I use `%` string formatting. But, as I discovered `f-string` is the new way of string formatting and it is faster as well, I want to use it. 
But, I am facing a problem when formatting a float into an integer using `f-string`. Following is what I have tried:
Using `%` string formatting

```
'%5d'%1223      # yields --> ' 1223'
'%5d'%1223.555  # yields --> ' 1223'
```

Using `f-string` formatting

```
f'{1223:5d}'     # yields --> ' 1223' ==> correct
f'{1223.555:5d}' # gives error
# error is "ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `f'{1223.555:5.0f}'`

Comment: If I try `f'{1223.555:5.0f}'`, it'll round off and yeild " 1224", which not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this error is that the format specifier `d` is specifically for formatting integers, not floats.You can use the general format specifier f instead.

```py
f'{int(1223.555):5d}'
```

Comment: In this way, it's giving `'1223.555000'` which is not what I want. Is there any other standard way to do it?

Comment: I just edited the answer, is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah. But, it's hack. Anyways, this is the only, I guess. Thanks though!

Comment: @SatishThorat It's not a hack. The old style formatting (% operator) implicitly converts float to int when the format specifier is d. The output you want is a float converted to int (rounded down) so why is converting the float to int a hack?

Comment: Ohh.. That's the difference. Thanks for making it clear.